# Reading data from edbpostgres into R (date problem)

Tags: r, postgresql, date, rpostgresql, edb

I have a problem with importing data from edb postgres into R (with RPostgres). I using this code:

```
library(RPostgres)
conn <- dbConnect(Postgres(), dbname = 'xx', host = 'xx', port = 'xx', 
                  user = 'xx', password = 'xx',
                  options="-c search_path=xx")

a=dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM xx")
```

After importing data into R is all Ok exept all column with date which become corruped. A few exemples:

```
postgres value: 2009-11-02  after importing in R: 0231-08-11
postgres value: 2009-08-12  after importing in R: 1206-01-15
```

data type in postgres for this column is date. If I read from postgres column (date) with query:

```
".. to_char(column_with_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') as column_with_date .."
```

then I get ok data in R but data type in R is not date but character.

I tried the same with importing the same data from mysql base into R (with RMySQL) and in this case data are noncorrupted . Used code:

```
library(RMySQL)
conn <-  dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "xx", password = "xx", dbname = "xx", host = "xx" )
a=dbGetQuery(conn,"select* from xx ")
```

Thank you

Comment: I have to believe this is a driver(RPostgres) issue. Probably raise this here:https://github.com/r-dbi/RPostgres/issues

Comment: Can you show us your schema?  For standard Date and Datetime types all relevant R packages --- including the RPostgreSQL package I co-wrote/mentored/maintained -- should just work.

Comment: Hi, sorry but I do not know exactly about which schema you talk about. I checked little bit in postgresql.conf and found this:

```
#edb_redwood_date = on   # translate DATE to TIMESTAMP(0)
edb_redwood_date = off   # translate TIMESTAMP(0) to DATE
```

Is maybe timestamp a reasons why R cannot read read date correct?